# Trouble recreating mud texture from image

Tags: texturing, pbr

I'm very new to PBR textures in blender and experimenting with them. I'm trying to recreating the look of the mud closely engulfing the woman in this picture using PBR but I'm having a lot more trouble than I thought... does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something close to this?

[image]

I've mixed the *Texture Coordinate* with a *Musgrave* in order to get twisted noise later. There are 2 levels of noise to get some bumps. I've put a Separate XYZ into the Roughness to get something more glossy into the lower parts as if they were more humid. For the color, a mix of 2 greyish blue. Just before the *Output*, a *Glossy* mixed with a *Layer Weight* as factor in order to have additional glossiness on the surface:

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you! This looks pretty good, I'll try copying it and I'll play close attention to how each node affects the material